# Set commands after an If command

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, set

Trying to make a quiz show.bat file and having trouble with the If-Set coding:

```
:10    
echo @: (Press any key to continue)
pause >nul
cls
echo Bonus Question 1:
echo Translate the letters in CAPS.
echo @: Copy the sentence and translate the words in CAPITALS.
echo Il nome di mia ZIA e Gabriella e il nome di mio ZIO e Nick.
echo @: Careful, you only get 3 goes!
echo @: now you try!
set /p BonusAnswer1=">"
set /p BonusAnswer1=">"
if "%BonusAnswer1%"=="Il nome di mia aunty Gabriella e il nome di mio uncle Nick. echo well done! &goto:11
if "%BonusAnswer1%"=="Hint" echo @: Copy the sentence and translate ZIA and ZIO. Only put a capital for Il, Gabriella and Nick. &goto:10
```

here is where I have the problem:

```
if "%Bonus1Tries%"=="3" set Bonus1Tries=2 &echo you only have %Bonus1Tries% left!
```

the only part of that coding that isn't working is it says:

```
you only have 3 tries left!
```

instead of

```
you only have 2 tries left!
```

which means that

**set Bonus1Tries=2**

isn't working.
Can you help please and thank you in advance! -Batch Man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

inside a code block you need `delayed expansion`, or you split the command (if possible):

```
if "%Bonus1Tries%"=="3" set "Bonus1Tries=2"
if "%Bonus1Tries%"=="2" echo you only have %Bonus1Tries% left!
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable delayed expansion

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set VAR=before
set VAR=after & echo immediate:%VAR%, delayed:!VAR!
ENDLOCAL
```

As explained by [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/23/714650.aspx)